# Optimizing ST_Within query to count lightning occurrences inside country

Tags: postgis, intersection

I just started learning PostGIS, and right now i'm trying to count the
number of lightning strikes in my country (Brazil in this case).

I have the following tables:

earth_feed --> This holds the `geometry(Point, 4326)`, `lon`, `lat` and some other info about a specific lightning occurrence.

brasil_shape --> This table has a single row `geometry(MultiPolygon, 4326)` which is the outfit of Brazil.

My query is for 14-January (the whole table is for Jan/2014, it's a test table)

```
SELECT COUNT(earth_feed.geom) FROM
earth_feed as earth, 
brasil_shape as brasil
WHERE 
EXTRACT('day' FROM date_occur) = 14 AND
ST_WITHIN(earth.geom, brasil.geom)
```

This query takes about 5 minutes to complete, and for this day we had about 200k lightning occurrences. Also, the table indexes seems to be ok:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_light_geom
  ON earth_feed
  USING gist
  (geom);
```

So i have 2 questions:

1 - Is this a 'normal' execution time? Brazil has continental dimensions and a lot of lightning occurrences.

2 - It seems that the shapefile for the country outline is being 'pulled' at each comparison. Here's part of the EXPLAIN output:

```
->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..9.58 rows=1 width=32)"
     ...
     ->  Seq Scan on brasil_shape brasil  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=32)
```

This affirmation is correct?

3 - The country outline is a `MultiPolygon`, so what happens if i change this shapefile to one having a smaller grid (more polygons)? Will the index be more effective? (I didn't tried this yet).

---

Here's the full EXPLAIN output (i changed the names to make the post easiear to read)

```
"Aggregate  (cost=9.59..9.60 rows=1 width=32)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..9.58 rows=1 width=32)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on shape_brasil brasil  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=32)"
"        ->  Index Scan using idx_raios_diario_jan_2014_geom on raios_diario_jan_2014 earth  (cost=0.00..8.56 rows=1 width=32)"
"              Index Cond: (earthnetworks_geometry_raios && brasil.geom)"
"              Filter: ((date_part('day'::text, earthnetworks_dt_horario) = 14::double precision) AND _st_contains(brasil.geom, earthnetworks_geometry_raios))"
```

Comment: Do you have a spatial index on your lightning strike table?  An index on the table with your country's boundary probably wouldn't make much difference since it is just 1 row.

Comment: Yes, there are ok.

Comment: Have you tried with ST_Intersects rather than ST_Within? For point data it should return exactly the same results (points cannot share only a part of their geometry with a polygon), but the function itself is better optimized in PostGIS code.

Comment: I already tried this, it takes more or less the same time.

Comment: What are the specs for your database server?  Hardware might be an issue.  Also, would you mind posting the full output from EXPLAIN?  It may shed some light on the slowest part of your query and give an idea on how the query may be optimized.

Comment: Question edit. It's a Linux Server, i'll try to get more info on Hardware specs and post it here. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a shapefile, or have you converted the file into a PostGIS geometry column in PostgreSQL?  How many total rows are in the dataset?  How many of the total points are in Brasil? Have you constructed an index on the date_occur field?

Comment: Total rows: 192712. I believe about 80% or more are inside Brazil (a small part of Latin America is monitored too). Both columns were converted to geometry, and the index for date is missing (but the 'date part' of the query is very fast, i tested it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example of trying to do two things at once.  You want to index spatially *and* temporally, but you can only use one index at a time.  So you need to make some choices.

If your temporal constraint is more restrictive, you should create an index on the date_occur field, and fashion a query that uses it -- by using a BETWEEN operator or a pair of greater-than-equal and less-than around the target date.

If your spatial component is more restrictive, then you've got a another issue -- spatial fragmentation.  Even though the spatial index is finding all the rows that are within your search envelope, the act of joining back to the table from the index is *very* inefficient (in essence, a full table scan).

There are many possible solutions to this, but they involve changing the table:

1. Add a country_code field to the table, then query with just attributes (and drop the spatial index if it slows down access)
2. Extract all the data as a series of country queries (or first-order political boundaries, or a systematic set of grid tiles), so that neighboring rows are spatially co-located.
3. If the table continues to grow, perform regular maintenance to optimize temporal windows (week or month) by spatial component
4. All of the above

Comment: So are you suggesting that i use a different country-outline shp file? ( my question 3 above). The lightning occurrence has no country flag, just date, lon, lat (and geometry). Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I just upload a new shp file of a Estate divided by municipalities, and it took less than 1 sec to count the occurrences within this area, very fast!

Comment: A very complex search geometry will slow down evaluation, but I'm suggesting you only pay that evaluation cost once, by adding a column, not paying it with every query.  Right now you've structured the most inefficient possible query -- a fragmented spatial search for only 20% reduction in row count.

Comment: I'm confused now, sorry...i cannot add country codes to any column, so the way to go  would be to run  he same query by state and sum up values? I did a quick test, and it seems to work very fast once a fragment the State by small regions. So i can do this for all 26 States in Brazil and sum up.

Comment: You may run into topology issues if you do it this way -- What happens to points which fall exactly on state borders?  Are they counted twice, or not at all?

Comment: I didn't know this could happen. ST_WITHIN will not solve this border issue for me?

Comment: No, it will not.  ST_Within is true when the point is *within* the geometry, so any points on state boundaries will not be found.